# How to find and connect text strings

Tags: vba, outlook

We had an old system, that sent us emails like this

**Name:** Firstname Familyname

**Address:** Street

**E-post:** some@thi.ng

and we used Outlook macro to transfer information to Excel, like this

```
        If InStr(1, vText(i), "Name: ") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), "Name: ")
            x1Sheet.Range("A" & lastrow) = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If
        If InStr(1, vText(i), "E-post: ") > 0 Then
            vItem = Split(vText(i), "E-post: ")
            x1Sheet.Range("D" & lastrow) = Trim(vItem(1))
        End If
```

However, this system was old, and we had to change to another system, that sends emails like this

**Customer info:** Firstname, Familyname, Address row 1, Address row 2, E-post, Whatnot

And we still need to get "Firstname Familyname" to Excel in column A and "e-post" to column D. How can I find text between commas and connect them as new text string if needed?

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is the customer info always in that order?

Answer (score 0):

Outlook allows for an email to have a text body, an Html body and/or a RTF body.  I have never seen a RTF body so I cannot comment on them.  I believe most emails today are sent with an Html body only and Outlook then creates a text body from the Html body according to a few simple rules.  My reason for this belief is that most text bodies conform to the same simple format but a few look very different and have clearly been constructed to look good with an email package that does not handle Html.

Your existing code must split the text body on CRLF to creates lines which are stored in `vText`.  You then have a loop that checks each line in `vTest`.  The code you show would be within that loop.

You show us how the Html body displays but that does not reliably show us what the text body looks like.  Try the following code.  If the result is satisfactory, I will show you how to convert it to the code you want.

Add these statements at the top of your routine:

```
Dim InxPart As Long
Dim LinePart() As String
```

Replace you existing check code with this:

```
If Left$(vText(i), 15) = "Customer info: " Then
  LinePart = Split(Mid$(vText(i), 16), ",")
  Debug.Print LinePart(0)
  Debug.Print LinePart(1)
  Debug.Print LinePart(4)
  Debug.Assert False
  Exit For
End If
```

If the code appears to do nothing, it means the code has not found "Customer info: ".

If the code stops at the `Debug.Assert False` statement, and you should see something like this in the Immediate Window:

```
John
Doe
JohnDoe@AcmeProducts.ng
```

If you do, then a simple change to my code will give the effect you seek.  If not, we will need to investigate your text body in more detail.

**Edit**  Code to allow investigation.

`InStr` will find a substring anywhere within a string.  `Left$` requires the substring to start the string.  Perhaps there are one or more leading spaces.  Perhaps there are more embedded spaces than the display suggests.  Perhaps there are non-break spaces.  Rather than experiment so see what works, let us perform a proper diagnosis.

Please add this function to your module.

```
Public Function TidyTextForDspl(ByVal Text As String) As String

  ' Tidy Text for display by replacing white space with visible strings:
  '   Leave single space unchanged
  '   Replace single LF by                 ‹lf›
  '   Replace single CR by                 ‹cr›
  '   Replace single TB by                 ‹tb›
  '   Replace single non-break space by    ‹nbs›
  '   Replace single CRLF by               ‹crlf›
  '   Replace multiple spaces by           ‹n s›       where n is number of repeats
  '   Replace multiple LFs by              ‹n lf›      of white space character
  '   Replace multiple CRs by ‹cr› or      ‹n cr›
  '   Replace multiple TBs by              ‹n tb›
  '   Replace multiple non-break spaces by ‹n nbs›
  '   Replace multiple CRLFs by            ‹n crlf›

  ' 15Mar16  Coded
  '  3Feb19  Replaced "{" (\x7B) and "}" (\x7D) by "‹" (\u2039) and "›" (\u203A)
  '          on the grounds that the angle quotation marks were not likely to
  '          appear in text to be displayed.
  '  5Feb19  Add code to treat CRLF as unit
  ' 28Mar19  Code to calculate PosWsChar after "<x>...<x>" converted to "<n x>"
  '          incorrect if "<x>...<x>" at the start of the string.  Unlikely it
  '          was correct in other situations but this did not matter since the
  '          calculated value would be before the next occurrence of "<x>...<x>".
  '          But, if the string was near the beginning of the string, the
  '          calculated value was negative and the code crashed.

  Dim InsStr As String
  Dim InxWsChar As Long
  Dim NumWsChar As Long
  Dim PosWsChar As Long
  Dim RetnVal As String
  Dim WsCharCrnt As Variant
  Dim WsCharValue As Variant
  Dim WsCharDspl As Variant

  WsCharValue = VBA.Array(" ", vbCr & vbLf, vbLf, vbCr, vbTab, Chr(160))
  WsCharDspl = VBA.Array("s", "crlf", "lf", "cr", "tb", "nbs")

  RetnVal = Text

  ' Replace each whitespace individually
  For InxWsChar = 0 To UBound(WsCharValue)
    RetnVal = Replace(RetnVal, WsCharValue(InxWsChar), "‹" & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›")
  Next

  ' Look for repeats. If found replace <x> by <n x>
  For InxWsChar = 0 To UBound(WsCharValue)
    'Debug.Assert InxWsChar <> 1
    PosWsChar = 1
    Do While True
      InsStr = "‹" & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›"
      PosWsChar = InStr(PosWsChar, RetnVal, InsStr & InsStr)
      If PosWsChar = 0 Then
        ' No [more] repeats of this <x>
        Exit Do
      End If
      ' Have <x><x>.  Count number of extra <x>x
      NumWsChar = 2
      Do While Mid(RetnVal, PosWsChar + NumWsChar * Len(InsStr), Len(InsStr)) = InsStr
        NumWsChar = NumWsChar + 1
      Loop
      RetnVal = Mid(RetnVal, 1, PosWsChar - 1) & _
                "‹" & NumWsChar & " " & WsCharDspl(InxWsChar) & "›" & _
                Mid(RetnVal, PosWsChar + NumWsChar * Len(InsStr))
      PosWsChar = PosWsChar + Len(InsStr) + Len(NumWsChar)

    Loop
  Next

  ' Restore any single spaces
  RetnVal = Replace(RetnVal, "‹" & WsCharDspl(0) & "›", " ")

  TidyTextForDspl = RetnVal

End Function
```

Please add something like this above the loop:

```
Debug.Print TidyTextForDspl(Mid$(.Body, 1, 200))
```

As per niton’s comment, it would have been helpful if you had included more of your code.  I have written `.Body` but you might need `MyMailItem.Body` or something similar.

My statement displays the first 200 characters of the text body with every space, carriage return and linefeed visible so we can know exactly what is there.  I am assuming that the “Customer info” line is near the beginning of the text body.  If it is further down, you will need to increase 1.  What we need is to see is the line above and the line below as well as the entire “Customer info” line so we can know how best to extract the parts of the line.

Please add the output created by the Debug.Print statement to your question or a comment.

Comment: Thank you, I already thought I got it working, but no. 

This is still working
        If InStr(1, vText(i), "Customer info: ") > 0 Then
But this one doesn't find anything
        If Left$(vText(i), 15) = "Customer info: " Then

Comment: @legotera  I have added some diagnostic code to my answer.  Please add it to your code and report back.

Comment: Sorry for delay, I got swamped with work. Where do I begin again... So this is As Outlook.MailItem. Maybe it's easier to drop the whole text to a cell in Excel and let that vba code handle splitting?

Comment: I do not believe the text  in the email is exactly what you think it is. Perhaps there is an extra space somewhere. I have added a complete new routine to my answer which you should add to your module. The new routine converts all the spaces, carriage returns, etc. in a string to visible characters so it is easy to see exactly what the string contains. I have also added a Debug.Print statement which I need you to add to your routine. The Debug.Print statement calls the new routine and writes its output to the Immediate Window. If you add that output to your answer it will help with diagnosis.

Comment: @legotera  The VBA code to split a string is the same in Excel VBA and Outlook VBA.  Copying the entire text to an Excel cell will not help.  Look in my answer for "**Edit** Code to allow investigation."  Read the new text for a fuller explanation of what I need you to do. It might help if you included more of your code in your question.